# How to differentiate two arrays by values in php?

Tags: php

I have a dropdown which is appeared with some default selected values &  the user can change the default selection. So how to differentiate the pre selected and new selected values. All the logic is written for role.

```
$value = ['34', '36']; // the changed values of the dropdown 
$input_role_count = count($value);
$user_details['role'] = ['34', '36']; // for default selection

$user_role_count  = count($user_details['role']);  

if($input_role_count > $user_role_count) {
  foreach ($value as $rolekey => $rolevalue) {
    $role_arr  =  [];
    if(!(in_array($rolevalue, $user_details['role']))) {
      array_push($role_arr, $rolevalue);
      //print_r($rolevalue);
    }
  }
} else {                
  foreach ($user_details['role']  as $rolekey2 => $rolevalue2) {     
  $role_arr =  [];
   if(!(in_array($rolevalue2, $value))) {
      array_push($role_arr, $rolevalue2);echo 'Not matched';
      //print_r($role_arr);
    }
  } 
}
```

The $value array could be ['34'], ['34', '36'], ['new']. I want to save the the value of the dropdown($value) which is stored $role_arr in if there is something is not matched with $user_details['role']. I have written my own logic but It doesn't work in each case. [image]

Comment: It's a little unclear what your question/goal is here. Can you describe what you're trying to do with more detail?

Comment: Maybe check out `array_diff`

Comment: array_diff is not useful in this case

Comment: No one knows the case besides you.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating, why do you need to compare them? Surely the new values are the ones you want. If they haven't been changed by the user, then they'll still be the default values, if they have been changed then you've got the new values. Just store what you get sent and it'll either stay as default or be updated to the user's choices

Comment: because data is not saved directly it goes in temporary table first